# Class Based Views filtering with "def get_queryset(self):" - Assistance with solving issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am trying to filter Data in my Web application and having issues to make it work properly.
My application has User model, to whom I assign different programs. Each program contain different exercises.

Program Model:

```
class Program(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    program_name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Program View:

```
class ProgramListView(ListView):
    model = Program
    template_name = 'program/prog.html' 
    context_object_name = 'programs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Program.objects.filter(patient=self.request.user)
```

Program Template:

```
{% extends "program/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> Please Choose your Program according to your Plan</h3>
    {% for program in programs %}
        <article class="media content-section">
            <div class="media-body">
                <div class="article-metadata">
                    <a class="mr-2" href="{% url 'program-detail' program.id %}">Program Name - {{ program.program_name }}</a>
                </div>
                    <p class="article-content">Date Posted - {{ program.date_posted }}</p>
                </div>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Exercise Model:

```
class Exercise(models.Model):
    program = models.ForeignKey(Program, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default="")
    description = models.TextField(default="")
    load_share = models.TextField(default="")
    breath_method = models.TextField(default="")
    recovery_method = models.TextField(default="")
    measure_method = models.TextField(default="")
    notes = models.TextField(default="")
    extra_info = models.TextField(default="")
    reps = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
    sets = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Exercises View (ProgramDetailView):

```
class ProgramDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Exercise
    context_object_name = 'exercises'

    def get_queryset(self):
        program_num = get_object_or_404(Program, pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
        return Exercise.objects.filter(program=program_num)
```

Exercises Template:

```
{% extends "program/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <h3> Program Exercises List</h3>
    {% for exercise in exercises %}

        <h3>{{ exercise.name }}</h3>
        <h3>{{ exercise.description }}</h3>

    {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

The Url's:

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views
from .views import ProgramListView, ProgramDetailView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='web-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='web-about'),
    path('programs/', ProgramListView.as_view(), name='web-programs'),
    path('programs/<int:pk>/', ProgramDetailView.as_view(), name='program-detail'),
```

My Program page works well, it shows me all the different programs the User was assign with.
Now, when I try to see the Program exercises (connects to the DetailView), it doesnt work.
I am trying to get the PK of the program and filter it with the help of the

```
get_object_or_404
```

The issues I encounter:

1. Only "pk=1" works (only the first program within the list), it shows me this error though -

```
TypeError at /programs/1/
'Exercise' object is not iterable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/programs/1/
Django Version: 3.1
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'Exercise' object is not iterable
Exception Location: C:\Users\shai3\Python\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py, line 167, in render
Python Executable:  C:\Users\shai3\Python\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.5
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\shai3\\PycharmProjects\\website',
 'C:\\Users\\shai3\\Python\\python38.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\shai3\\Python\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\shai3\\Python\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\shai3\\Python',
 'C:\\Users\\shai3\\Python\\lib\\site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 03 Sep 2020 12:04:29 +0300
```

It seems like he doesn't get all the exercises in the Data base, It can't use the "For" loop

2.When i try the rest of the programs within the list, I get 404 error -

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/programs/2/
Raised by:  program.views.ProgramDetailView
No exercise found matching the query

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

In the SQLite, I do have exercises related to "pk=2" so I am assuming that it at list show me the same error has "pk=1" but it seems like he cant find the exercises in the data base.

Appreciates your help.

Thanks, and I hope I didn't miss any "Code lines".

Comment: You have `model = Exercise` for `class ProgramDetailView`. Therefore you are displaying multiple exercises in that view, which suggests it should be a `ListView`, not `DetailView`. The alternative would be to use a `DetailView` with `model = Program`, then loop through the related exercises with `{% for exercise in program.exercise_set.all %}`.

Comment: I changed the class to ListView, now it works perfect. Thank for your help!